# how to command to get vlc latest version?

Tags: command-line, vlc

I want to get vls latest version safely. I have brew.How could I type to terminal ? I dont wanna download it from a website since it may not be safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curl -O http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net/videolan/vlc/2.1.2/macosx/vlc-2.1.2.dmg`
This is the official OS X build by Felix Kuehne, the main OS X VLC maintainer; I doubt 3rd party repositories host OS X / Cocoa specific builds like this one.

Comment: I typed to terminal curl -O http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net/videolan/vlc/2.1.2/macosx/vlc-2.1.2.dmg                                                  I think it is installed but I could not find it. I typed which vlc but terminal says nothing

Comment: You will find it in the current directory (the directory from which you ran the command). The file will be called `vlc-2.1.2.dmg` and inside it (type `open vlc-2.1.2.dmg` if in doubt) you'll find `vlc.app`. What I gave you is basically code for downloading it from an official VLC mirror though.

Comment: oww yes I see thnx this helped.